# Error: "l8.filter is not a function"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vegetation-index

I'm writing a code to calculate vegetation indexes and plot charts for each index. In the same script I've added the code to make a GUI for the same.
I'm getting the error:

> Error: "l8.filter is not a function"

I've done the basic troubleshooting but couldn't get why this error is popping. Here's the link and the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fshubhra29yadav%2Fndvi1%3AVertex

```
function maskClouds(image) {
  
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = 1<<3;
    var cloudsBitMask = 1<<5;  
    
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
    
     // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
    .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
    
      // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
  
  var addNDVI = function (image){
    var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
  };

  var addEVI = function (image){
    var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - Red) / (NIR + 6 * Red - 7.5 * Blue + 1))',{    // C1=6, C2=7.5, L=1
    'NIR': image.select('B5'),
    'Red': image.select('B4'),
    'Blue': image.select('B2'),
    }).rename('EVI');
  evi = evi.toFloat();
  return image.addBands(evi);
  };
  var addNDWI = function (image){ 
    var ndwi = image.expression(
    'NDWI = (Green – NIR) / (Green + NIR)',{
      'Green': image.select('B3'),
      'NIR': image.select('B5')
    });
  ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B3']).rename('NDWI');
  return image.addBands(ndwi);
  };
  
 var addMSAVI = function (image){
   var msavi = image.expression(
   '(2 * nir + 1 - ( (2 * nir + 1)**2 - 8 * (nir -red) )**(1/2) ) / 2',{
     'nir': image.select('B5'),
     'red': image.select('B4')
   });
  msavi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('MSAVI');
  return image.addBands(msavi);
 };

////Mapping Indices over a collection
var withNDVI = l8.map(addNDVI);
var withEVI = l8.map(addEVI);
var withNDWI = l8.map(addNDWI);
var withMSAVI = l8.map(addMSAVI);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
//filterDate()
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDVI)
.map(addEVI)
.map(addNDWI)
.map(addMSAVI)
.mean();

print(l8);

var m = {}
m.imgInfo = {
  bands: {
    'NDVI': {
      bname: 'NDVI',
      color: 'green',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1, 
        palette: ['#edf8fb', '#ccece', '#99d8c9', '#66c2a4', '#2ca25f', '#006d2c']
      }
    },
    'EVI': {
      bname: 'EVI',
      color: 'grey',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
        palette: ['#feebe2', '#fcc5c0', '#fa9fb5', '#f768a1', '#c51b8a', '#7a0177']
      }
    }, 
    'NDWI': {
      bname: 'NDWI',
      color: 'blue',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
        palette: ['#eff3ff', '#c6dbef', '#9ecae1', '#6baed6', '#3182bd', '#08519c']
      }
    },
    'MSAVI': {
      bname: 'MSAVI',
      color: 'red',
      vis: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1, 
        palette: ['#fee5d9', '#fcbba1', '#fc9272', '#fb6a4a', '#de2d26', '#a50f15']
      }
    }
  },
  startYear: 2014,
    endYear: 2021
}

var c = {}

c.controlPanel = ui.Panel()

c.map = ui.Map();

c.info = {};
c.info.titleLabel = ui.Label('Title goes here')
c.info.aboutLabel = ui.Label({value: 'Description', style: {fontSize: '10px'}})
c.info.panel = ui.Panel([c.info.titleLabel, c.info.aboutLabel]);

c.selectYear = {};
c.selectYear.label = ui.Label({value: 'Select a year to display', style: {fontSize: '10px', Color: 'grey'}});
c.selectYear.slider = ui.Slider({
  min: m.imgInfo.startYear,
  max: m.imgInfo.endYear,
  step: 1,
  style: {width: '200px', padding: '10px 0px 0px 20px'}
}) ;

c.selectYear.panel = ui.Panel([c.selectYear.label, c.selectYear.slider]);

c.selectBand = {};
c.selectBand.label = ui.Label('Select a band to display');
c.selectBand.selector = ui.Select(Object.keys(m.imgInfo.bands));
c.selectBand.panel = ui.Panel([c.selectBand.label, c.selectBand.selector]);

c.legend = {};
c.legend.title = ui.Label();
c.legend.colorbar = ui.Thumbnail(ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0));
c.legend.leftLabel = ui.Label('[min]');
c.legend.centerLabel = ui.Label();
c.legend.rightLabel = ui.Label('[max]');
c.legend.labelPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    c.legend.leftLabel,
    c.legend.centerLabel,
    c.legend.rightLabel,
  ],
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')
});
c.legend.panel = ui.Panel([
  c.legend.title,
  c.legend.colorbar,
  c.legend.labelPanel
]);

c.chart = {};
c.chart.shownButton = ui.Button('Hide chart');
c.chart.container = ui.Panel();  // will hold the dynamically generated chart. 
c.chart.chartPanel = ui.Panel([c.chart.shownButton, c.chart.container]);

c.controlPanel.add(c.info.panel);
c.controlPanel.add(c.selectYear.panel);
c.controlPanel.add(c.selectBand.panel);

c.map.add(c.legend.panel);
c.map.add(c.chart.chartPanel);

ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(c.controlPanel);
ui.root.add(c.map);

var s = {};

s.opacityWhiteMed = {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
};
s.opacityWhiteNone = {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
};
s.aboutText = {
  fontSize: '13px',
  color: '505050'
};
s.widgetTitle = {
  fontSize: '15px',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  margin: '8px 8px 0px 8px',
  color: '383838'
};
s.stretchHorizontal = {
  stretch: 'horizontal'
};
s.noTopMargin = {
  margin: '0px 8px 8px 8px'
};
s.smallBottomMargin = {
  margin: '8px 8px 4px 8px'
};
s.bigTopMargin = {
  margin: '24px 8px 8px 8px'
};
s.divider = {
  backgroundColor: 'F0F0F0',
  height: '4px',
  margin: '20px 0px'
};

c.info.titleLabel.style().set({
  fontSize: '20px',
  fontWeight: 'bold'
})

c.info.titleLabel.style().set(s.bigTopMargin);
c.info.aboutLabel.style().set(s.aboutText);

c.selectYear.slider.style().set(s.stretchHorizontal);
c.selectYear.label.style().set(s.widgetTitle);

c.selectBand.selector.style().set(s.stretchHorizontal);
c.selectBand.label.style().set(s.widgetTitle);

c.controlPanel.style().set({
  width: '25%',
  padding: '0px'
})

c.map.style().set({
  cursor: 'crosshair'
})

c.map.setOptions('HYBRID')

c.chart.chartPanel.style().set({
  position: 'bottom-right',
  shown: false
});
c.chart.chartPanel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteMed);
c.chart.shownButton.style().set({
  margin: '0px 0px',
});

c.legend.title.style().set({
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '12px',
  color: '383838'
});
c.legend.title.style().set(s.opacityWhiteNone);
c.legend.colorbar.style().set({
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  margin: '0px 8px',
  maxHeight: '20px'
});
c.legend.leftLabel.style().set({
  margin: '4px 8px',
  fontSize: '12px'
});
c.legend.leftLabel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteNone);
c.legend.centerLabel.style().set({
  margin: '4px 8px',
  fontSize: '12px',
  textAlign: 'center',
  stretch: 'horizontal'
});
c.legend.centerLabel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteNone);
c.legend.rightLabel.style().set({
  margin: '4px 8px',
  fontSize: '12px'
});
c.legend.rightLabel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteNone);
c.legend.panel.style().set({
  position: 'bottom-left',
  width: '200px',
  padding: '0px'});
c.legend.panel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteMed);
c.legend.labelPanel.style().set(s.opacityWhiteNone);

////////////////////FUNCTIONS/////////////////////////

///gets list of values for a specified property name
function getPropertyValueList(dataModelDict, propertyName){
  var result = [];
  for (var key in dataModelDict){
    result.push(dataModelDict[key][propertyName]);
  }
  return result;
}

function updateLegend() {
  c.legend.title.setValue(c.selectBand.selector.getValue() + ' (%)');
  c.legend.colorbar.setParams({
    bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
    dimensions: '100x10',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: m.imgInfo.bands[c.selectBand.selector.getValue()].vis.palette
  });
  c.legend.leftLabel.setValue(
    m.imgInfo.bands[c.selectBand.selector.getValue()].vis.min);
  c.legend.centerLabel.setValue(
    m.imgInfo.bands[c.selectBand.selector.getValue()].vis.max / 2);
  c.legend.rightLabel.setValue(
    m.imgInfo.bands[c.selectBand.selector.getValue()].vis.max);
}

function updateMap() {
  var year = c.selectYear.slider.getValue();
  var band = c.selectBand.selector.getValue();
  
  var img = l8.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', parseInt(year, 10))).select(m.imgInfo.bands[band].bname);
  var layer = ui.Map.Layer(m.imgInfo.bands[band].vis, band + ',' + year);
  ui.Map.layers.set(0, layer);
}

function drawChart (coords){
 
  if (!coords.lon) {
    return null;
  }

  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)
  var validDataTest = l8.first().select(0).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: point,
    scale: l8.first().projection().nominalScale()
  });
  if (!validDataTest.get(validDataTest.keys().get(0)).getInfo()) {
    return null;
  }  
  if (!c.chart.chartPanel.style().get('shown')) {
    c.chart.chartPanel.style().set('shown', true);
  }
  if (c.chart.shownButton.getLabel() == 'Show chart') {
    c.chart.container.style().set({shown: true});
    c.chart.shownButton.setLabel('Hide chart');
  }
  
  var styleChartAxis = {
    italic: false,
    bold: true
  };
  var styleChartArea = {
    width: '600px',
    height: '255px',
    margin: '0px',
    padding: '0px'
  }; 
  
  var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: m.col.select(
      getPropertyValueList(m.imgInfo.bands, 'bname')),
    region: point.buffer(radius),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: m.col.first().projection().nominalScale()
  })
  .setSeriesNames(Object.keys(m.imgInfo.bands))
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
    titlePosition: 'none',
    colors: getPropertyValueList(m.imgInfo.bands, 'color'),
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Year',
      titleTextStyle: styleChartAxis
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Stacked percent cover',
      titleTextStyle: styleChartAxis,
    },
    legend: {maxLines: 2},
    isStacked: 'percent'
  });
  chart.style().set(styleChartArea);
  
  c.chart.container.widgets().reset([chart]);
}

function updateLegend(){
  legendTitle.setValue(selectBand.getValue());
  legendColorbar.setParams({
    bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
    dimensions: '100x10',
    format: 'png',
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: imgInfo.bands[selectBand.getValue()].vis.palette
  })
}

function showHideChart() {
  var shown = true;
  var label = 'Hide chart';
  if (c.chart.shownButton.getLabel() == 'Hide chart') {
    shown = false;
    label = 'Show chart';
  }
  c.chart.container.style().set({shown: shown});
  c.chart.shownButton.setLabel(label);
}
c.chart.shownButton.onClick(showHideChart);


function updateUrlParamYear(newValue){
  ui.url.set('year', newValue);
}
c.selectYear.slider.onChange(updateUrlParamYear);
c.selectYear.slider.onChange(updateMap);

function updateUrlParamBand(newValue){
  var bands = getPropertyValueList(m.imgInfo.bname);
  ui.url.set('band', m.imgInfo.bands[newValue].bname);
}
c.selectBand.selector.onChange(updateUrlParamBand);
c.selectBand.selector.onChange(updateMap);
c.selectBand.selector.onChange(updateLegend);

function updateUrlParamMap(newMapParams) {
  ui.url.set('lat', newMapParams.lat);
  ui.url.set('lon', newMapParams.lon);
  ui.url.set('zoom', newMapParams.zoom);
}
c.map.onChangeBounds(ui.util.debounce(updateUrlParamMap, 100));

function updateUrlParamChart(newChartParams) {
  ui.url.set('chart_lat', newChartParams.lat);
  ui.url.set('chart_lon', newChartParams.lon);
}
c.map.onClick(drawChart);
c.map.onClick(updateUrlParamChart);


//////////////initialize//////////////
function findKey(dataModelDict, propertyName, propertyValue){
  // Find the first dictionary key for a specified property value.
  for (var key in dataModelDict) {
    if (dataModelDict[key][propertyName] == propertyValue) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Set model state based on URL parameters or default values.
c.map.setCenter({
  lon: ui.url.get('lon', -95.0),
  lat: ui.url.get('lat', 39.0),
  zoom: ui.url.get('zoom', 5)
});

c.selectYear.slider.setValue(ui.url.get('year', 2000), false);

c.selectBand.selector.setValue(
  findKey(m.imgInfo.bands, 'bname', ui.url.get('band', 'AFGC')), 
  false);

// Render the map and legend.
updateMap();
updateLegend();

// Render the chart if applicable (chart_lon exists as URL param).
drawChart({lon: ui.url.get('chart_lon'), lat: ui.url.get('chart_lat')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you are calling `l8.filter()`.

```
  var img = l8.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', parseInt(year, 10))).select(m.imgInfo.bands[band].bname);
```

This and other parts of the code make sense if `l8` is an `ImageCollection`. But where it is defined:

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
//filterDate()
.map(maskClouds)
.map(addNDVI)
.map(addEVI)
.map(addNDWI)
.map(addMSAVI)
.mean();
```

You start with a collection, and take the mean of it. The mean of an `ImageCollection` is an `Image`. You can't do collection operations like filtering to an image.

So, you need to decide whether your script should be working with a single image or a collection, and make it consistent — either remove `mean()` or remove the `l8.filter()` and `l8.first()`.

Comment: On removing any one of 'mean()' and 'l8.filter()' I'm getting the error "Cannot read the property bname of undefined", which refers to the line 'var img = ee.Filter.eq('year', parseInt(year, 10)).select(m.imgInfo.bands[band].bname);'